# How can we implement transaction mechanism in Mongo DB data insertion using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I found that I am using MongoDB server 3.2 and it doesn't support sessions. Please help me to implement transaction in 3.2 version instead of updating server.

I used `StartSession()`, `StartTransaction()` methods for this, but I am getting exception like "*Sessions are not supported by this version of server*".

Comment: There is no easy way as mongo is not really transactional.  You could do it old school and implement some kind of manual workaround like insert and delete if further inserts/updates fail.